# Jackson cannot deserialize empty byte array/stream

Tags: java, jackson

Can I somehow alter ObjectMapper to be able to handle null and empty values?

Let's say that my value is read as

```
objectMapper.readValue(val, new TypeReference<Object>() {});
```

Where val is

```
val = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[] {});
```

I don't have control over value that is passed and I cannot check for buffer length prior to executing `readValue`.

I've tried configuring mapper with `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT` such as:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
```

But I still get the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input` error. Is it possible to somehow have Jackson ignore empty values and just return null?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to somehow have Jackson ignore empty values and just return null?

You can successfully dial with an empty byte array, or an empty input stream, by using a more low-level streaming API.

That's the core idea of how you can ensure that there's some to parse by employing a `JsonParser` before feeding the data into an `ObjectMapper`:

```
byte[] jsonBytes1 = {};
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonParser parser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(jsonBytes1);

JsonNode node = parser.readValueAsTree();
        
MyPojo myPojo = null;
        
if (node != null) {
    myPojo = mapper.treeToValue(node, MyPojo.class);
}
```

So we're parsing the input into a `JsonNode` and checking it manually, only if it's not null `ObjectMapper` comes into play.

If we extract this logic into a separate method, that's it might look like (Java 8 `Optional` might be handy in this case a return type):

```
public static <T> Optional<T> convertBytes(byte[] arr,
                                           Class<T> pojoClass,
                                           ObjectMapper mapper) throws IOException {
    
    JsonParser parser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(arr);
    JsonNode node = parser.readValueAsTree();
    
    return node != null ? Optional.of(mapper.treeToValue(node, pojoClass)) : Optional.empty();
}
```

#### Usage example

Consider a simple POJO:

```
public class MyPojo {
    private String name;
    
    // getter, setters and toString
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String source = """
        {
            "name" : "Alice"
        }
        """;
    
    byte[] jsonBytes1 = {};
    byte[] jsonBytes2 = source.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    System.out.println(convertBytes(jsonBytes1, MyPojo.class, mapper));
    System.out.println(convertBytes(jsonBytes2, MyPojo.class, mapper));
}
```

*Output:*

```
Optional.empty
Optional[Test.MyPojo(name=Alice)]
```

Comment: Thank you for an extensive answer, but what I've meant by not being able to check buffer length prior to invoking readValue is that I cannot change the part of the code where readValue is invoked. It will be invoked regardless of value that needs to be parsed.

Comment: @lovrodoe I doubt if there's a workaround that would allow to `ObjectMapper` directly. I've checked the [documented issues](https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j/issues), a case when `MismatchedInputException` is cause by an empty stream or an empty byte array is not described yet. You can try to open a new issue.